# Finding days between dates when string is contained in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've 2 Excel sheets, one called "Inventory" and the other called "BookDetails".

"Inventory" contains all sold books and the date they were sold.
"BookDetails" contains all the books and the date it was scanned

"Inventory" has a shorter name of the title, while "BookDetails" contains additional info beside the title.

example:

`(Inventory)`
[image: Inventory]

`(BookDetails)`
[image: BookDetails]

what I want to do is do is find the time in days between scanning and selling the book and place the value in an new column in "Inventory". In my file there are too many to do manually.

I'm assuming its along the lines of

```
If(BookDetails!A:A 'contains' Inventory!A2){

 BookDetails!DateScanned - Inventory!DateSold

}
```

Comment: Do you have it in the same file as two sheets or are they two separate files?

Comment: For your If statement, you could try a `Countif()`, `If Countif(Bookdetails!A:A,"*"&Inventory!A2&"*") > 0 Then ...` which will search BookDetails range A:A for what's in Inventory A2. Note, I'm using wildcards so if A2 has "man", the countif will hit if A:A has "superman","man","mandibles",etc. so you may want to adjust/remove the wildcard (you can remove completely if looking for an exact match).

Comment: do the description of the cover of the book `paperback` and `hardcover` are always within in the square brackets `[..]`? Because if they are consistent we have to remove them and then compare with the title, which is equal to the one on the inventor page

Comment: Can I assume that there is not a 1:1 correspondence between the lists (different order, non-matching number of entries if an item hasn't yet been scanned or  say 5 were sold and 1 has been scanned on each of several different dates)?

Comment: It seems like the logical place to calculate and display the interval would be in BookDetails, in a column next to Date Scanned.  Is this what you're envisioning, or do you need it in a third worksheet as implied by your pseudo-code example?

Comment: sorry about the late response, ill try answer all the questions now. 
the sheets are in the same file.
the square brackets are in the majority of them but they do also contain the authors name at the end of the title like "harry potter[hardcover] jk rowling".
I've looked into comparing isbns but unfortunately amazon have their own Asin in their reports and its not comparable without writing some code to transfer the number back.

Comment: the date would be preferably placed beside the inventory's "date sold"

Answer (score 0):

In your **Inventory** Sheet, use a formula such as this to lookup the Date Scanned in the **BookDetails** sheet, then calculate the difference between this date and Date Sold:

> =B2-VLOOKUP(A2,BookDetails!A:D,4,FALSE)

This assume B2 contains Date Sold, and the A:D columns in the **BookDetails** sheet contains Book, Author, Publisher, and Date Scanned. Obviously, you'll need to adjust. The 3rd argument value (4) indicates the index to the column containing Date Scanned (4th column).

Comment: The question is ambiguous, but it sounds like there may be more than one BookDetails record for each Inventory record.  Seems like the better approach would be to do this in the BookDetails sheet.  Parse the title using the "[", then do the lookup in the Inventory sheet.

Comment: not the best at explaining myself but ill try again none the less. bookdetails contains 1,555 books (which were sold or not sold). inventory only contains the books that were sold online (about 120 books). unfortunately there is no unique id for each book (which will soon be a problem) but at the moment we can assume that all 1,555 books have unique titles. all i have to go off is comparing the names of the book to get the date it was scanned.

Comment: Based on what you've described, if you want the 'Days since Scan' to be reported on your Inventory sheet, the VLookup() solution I suggested should work. Have you tried this method?